# Databinding MVC Grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, razor, data-binding

I am new to MVC architecture. I want to display MVC grid on my page but through databinding.

So currently in my controller I have created a list which I am returning to View.

```
Dim lst As New List(Of Employee)
.
.
Return View(lst)
```

In my View I have this code -->

```
@code
  @Html.Grid(Model).Named("grdGrid").Sortable(True).Columns(Function(col) col.Add(Function(o) o.Id)).Columns(Function(col) col.Add(Function(o) o.EmpName))
End Code
```

So here I am able to display the grid correctly.
On similar basis, is it possible to databind the grid?

If I am getting my code in a data table, and that data table I want to directly bind to my MVC Grid. I do not want to use list.

Thanks

Amruta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to this **[blog post](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/d551d3/how-to-load-partial-views-in-Asp-Net-mvc-using-jquery-ajax/)** to render the pages with partial view.

Posting a link because there might be many pros & cons in your code but you'll get better idea from the link I posted.

Comment: I am able to populate the grid in similar way, but I was just wondering if we can directly databind the grid in MVC. In Asp .Net we could directly provide the data source to grid. So is it possible to do that in MVC?

Comment: Yes that provides to bind directly to datasource, but for that you'll need to use WebGrid. Please review **[this example](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/615776/WebGrid-in-ASP-NET-MVC)**